# Click event within textarea not working in ie9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have an classic asp page. Everything is working fine in IE5,6,7,8,10,11(EDGE) except IE9.

There is a textarea, within this there are some ids, on click of these ids, I am redirecting to another page with that particular id where I clicked on.

I tried lots of things/ tricks for IE9 but not working:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,EmulateIE8,Edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

 <textarea name="txtA1" cols="10" rows="10" wrap="OFF" onFocus="this.blur();" onDblClick="getClick();" value style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"> </textarea>

function getClick(){

    var r, qlid, a1, Instid,Cnty,b1
     if(window.event.srcElement.isTextEdit)
           {
            r=window.event.srcElement.createTextRange();
     }else{
            var el=window.event.srcElement.parentTextEdit;
            r=el.createTextRange();
           }
     r.moveToPoint(window.event.x, window.event.y);
     r.expand("sentence");
     r.select();
     qlid = r.text; 
     qlid = qlid.substring(140,150);    

     a1 = qlid.indexOf('-');
     Instid = qlid.substring(0,a1);

     pmid = r.text; 
     pmid = pmid.substring(140,155);    

     b1 =  pmid.indexOf('!');
     Cnty =  pmid.substring(0,b1);

     if (trim(Cnty) != "") {         
         window.location.href = "Nats-inst.asp?Instid="+trim(Cnty);
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect! Now share the correct part of code...

Comment: sorry @MarcosPérezGude now check